# What is a good UI approach for a WPF dash-board-with-several-windows kind of application?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dashboard

I am developing a WPF desktop app for a small business. It will have a dashboard with 4 buttons that should show a corresponding window/form.

Examples -

1. Manage Entries
2. Admin
3. Reports
4. Help

Each of these has a separate form with lots of controls and stuff.

Is it best to have each of these as a separate window (including dashboard) and show them when a button is clicked in the dashboard?

Or is it possible to have just one window with these 4 buttons on top, and swap the contents below depending on the button?

I am kind of new to WPF apps so I don't know whats possible and what is the best-practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will find with WPF is nearly anything is possible from a UI perspective.

It is definitely possible having one window and swapping the contents below depending on the button. A pattern I like is [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) which has some interesting patterns and best practices on achieving composite windows in both WPF and Silverlight.

You could also look at the [MVVM pattern](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/), which is becoming really popular with WPF. [Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/my-mvvm-article-in-msdn-magazine/) has many great articles for this.

Also, if you are really new, have a look as User Controls, as this allows you to easily modularize certain sections.

What I found with myself was with my first few WPF applications, I approached it from a Winform's mindset - but then after really getting a second look at Binding, these other patterns really began to shine.

Answer (score 0):

One best-practice approach is to use *Composite Application Guidance*. Basically it is an application design approach which contains a *shell* and multiple *views* which are arranged inside it. Microsoft has released a CAG library called Prism through CodePlex, and has provided tutorials and documentation for it on MSDN.

[CodePlex Link: Composite WPF and Silverlight](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

[MSDN Link: Composite Client Application Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707819.aspx)